# What is the order of before_action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have two before_actions in base controller in order as follows :

```
before_action :method_1
before_action :method_2
```

But the execution is happening as ***`method_2`*** is being called first and then ***`method_1`*** . Just wanted to know if this is the normal behaviour of rails. Moreover this is important, as i need a value from ***`method_1`*** in ***`method_2`*** .

Comment: have you debugged the code? used breakpoints as well?

Comment: @GaganGupta yes, i have tried debugging and in every request the method_2 is being executed first.

Comment: `prepend_before_action :method_1`
then `before_action :method_2` will solve this issue

Comment: Is it a good option to use `prepend_before_action` ? As i had followed some documents where it has been suggested not to use `prepend_before_action`

Comment: it's fine and it depends on your use case. I've also read that but that guy wanted to use prepend_before_action for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good write ups online for the firing order of callbacks, such as [this one](https://reganchan.ca/blog/ordering-of-filters-in-rails-controllers/#:%7E:text=When%20using%20before_action%20%2C%20the%20filters,action%20as%20they%20are%20defined.).

In simple cases, `method_1` should fire before `method_2` (for `before_action` - note the order is reversed for `after_action`!). However this order can be changed by a few things such as inheritance from objects with overlapping callbacks, as described in the link above. If you need to get around this, `prepend_before_action` can be used as described in the comment chain.